# In recursive Make how to identify parent variable value from sub-make?

Tags: recursion, makefile

If `gmake VAR1=x` is invoked from a directory
which in turn invokes sub-makes with `gmake VAR1=y`
is there a way in sub-makefile to know the parent's `VAR1` variable value `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know: no.

But the parent can make a copy of the `VAR1`'s value in another variable, e.g. `PARENT_VAR1`:

```
ifneq ($(origin VAR1),undefined)
export PARENT_VAR1=$(VAR1)
endif
```

Then submake can still take the `VAR1`, and if needed, also interrogate the parent's `VAR1`.